# Estou com alguns problemas no meu código - Portugol

Tags: portugol

Enfim, eu estou criando um jogo no Portugol Studio (Show do Milhão), é um jogo de perguntas e respostas...

Porém, meu trabalho tem que ter o modo de **2 jogadores** (Multiplayer)

E eu não tenho ideia de como fazer esse Loop **na mesma pergunta** para que os **2 jogadores respondam**, e só assim ir pra **próxima pergunta**

Vou deixar parte do código aqui pra entenderem melhor

---

```
    {
     escreva("Digite nome/apelido do primeiro jogador: ")
     leia(nome_jogador1)
     escreva("Digite nome/apelido do segundo jogador: ")
     leia(nome_jogador2)
     limpa()

     escreva("Qual o nível de dificuldade que desejam jogar?\n")
     escreva("\n")
     escreva("1 - Fácil\n")
     escreva("2 - Médio\n")
     escreva("3 - Difícil\n")
     escreva("Digite o número da dificuldade aqui: ")
     leia(dificuldade)
     limpa()

     para (inteiro i = 1; i <= sorteios; i++) //Sortear qual jogador irá começar
    {
        valor_sorteado = u.sorteia(valor_inicial, valor_final)

        se (valor_sorteado==1) //Se o valor for 1, logo o jogador número 1 irá começar
        {
            escreva("O jogador ", nome_jogador1)
            escreva(" que irá começar a responder\n\n")
        }
        se (valor_sorteado==2) //Se o valor for 2, logo o jogador número 2 irá começar
        {
            escreva("O jogador ", nome_jogador2) 
            escreva(" que irá começar a responder\n\n")
        }
    }

     se (dificuldade==1)
    {
        escreva("Nível de dificuldade: Fácil\n\n")
        escreva("Pergunta nº1\n\n")
        escreva("Qual desses componentes, é um componente de armazenamento?\n")
        escreva("1 - HD\n")
        escreva("2 - Processador\n")
        escreva("3 - Memória Ram\n")
        escreva("4 - placa-mãe\n")
        escreva("5 - Fonte\n")
        escreva("Digite sua resposta aqui: ")
        leia(resposta1)

        se (resposta1==1)
        {
            escreva("\n")
            escreva("Você acertou!\n")
            escreva("----------------------------\n\n")
            acertos = acertos+1
        }
        senao
        {
            escreva("\n")
            escreva("Você errou, que pena.\n")
            escreva("----------------------------\n\n")
            erros = erros+1
        }

        escreva("Pergunta nº2\n\n")
        escreva("Qual o maior espaço de um disco abaixo?\n")
        escreva("1 - 500GB\n")
        escreva("2 - 250GB\n")
        escreva("3 - 1TB\n")
        escreva("4 - 40GB\n")
        escreva("5 - 80GB\n")
        escreva("Digite sua resposta aqui: ")
        leia(resposta2)

        se (resposta2==3)
        {
            escreva("\n")
            escreva("Você acertou!\n")
            escreva("----------------------------\n\n")
            acertos = acertos+1
        }
        senao
        {
            escreva("\n")
            escreva("Você errou, que pena.\n")
            escreva("----------------------------\n\n")
            erros = erros+1
        }
```

---

Se puderem me ajudar com isso, irei ficar muito grato.

Obs: Como eu posso identificar qual jogador foi **sorteado na primeira pergunta**? E ordenar para que os **2 jogadores respondam a mesma questão** (só assim pra ir pra próxima)!?

Obs²: *São 5 perguntas no modo fácil, 5 no modo médio e 5 no modo difícil... Cada pergunta com 5 alternativas (Já feito)*.

Comment: É algo sortido? Tipo no inicio do jogo para começar ou sortear as perguntas poder ser tanto para o primeiro quanto para o segundo sem uma ordem?